# Runtime sized arrays and pointer-decay

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, variable-length-array

I was testing some of the tools in the `type_traits` header over the new C++14 runtime sized arrays, consider the code below:

```
int g[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

template <typename T> void print(T &t)
{
    std::cout << "Type id:    " << typeid(T).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "is_array:   " << std::is_array<decltype(T)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "is_pointer: " << std::is_pointer<decltype(T)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "extent:     " << std::extent<decltype(T)>::value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print(g);
    return 0;
}
```

The static sized array `g` returns the following output:

```
Type id:    A11_i
is_array:   1
is_pointer: 0
extent:     11
```

The unmangled name `A11_i` I'm assuming that is **A**rray of **11** elements of type **int** so all is correct here, but with this new code:

```
void f(std::size_t s)
{
    int a[s];
    print(a);
}

int main()
{
    f(5);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting errors:

```
In function 'void f(std::size_t)':
error: no matching function for call to 'print(int [s])'

note: candidate is:
note: template<class T> void print(T&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   variable-sized array type 'int [s]' is not a valid template argument
```

I wasn't expecting that the size argument could be passed to the template but I was expecting an automatic array-to-pointer decay. I guess that the argument `T &` isn't suited for this kind of decay so I've tried to change the template signature to:

```
template <typename T> void print(T *&t)
```

With similar results:

```
In function 'void f(std::size_t)':
error: no matching function for call to 'print(int [s])'

note: candidate is:
note: template<class T> void print(T*&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types 'T*' and 'int [s]'
```

And I've noticed that the size variable on the runtime sized array seems to be tied to the type (instead of `mismatched types 'T*' and 'int [`**`5`**`]'` we're getting `mismatched types 'T*' and 'int [`**`s`**`]'`) this looks pretty weird.

So, what's the question?

- Why I'm not getting an array-to-pointer decay in this runtime sized array?
- Is the *variable* used to size the runtime sized array part of the type of the runtime sized array or I'm misunderstanding the error?

Comment: Note that you use VLA extension with `int a[s];`

Comment: A lot of compiler flags or code norms forbid to use a runtime sized array. (I know G++ with warning flags forbid it for example) It is possible that your compiler refuses to use it as a template.

Comment: To expand on Jarod42's comment, runtime sized arrays were proposed but not eventually included in the final c++14 standard.

Comment: My bad! I really thoguth that runtime sized arrays were included in C++14 (that's why I added the C++14 tag). Anyway it doesn't change the question: *why VLA doesn't decay to pointer in this example*?

Comment: Does it work with a precise-sized array ? Like if you test it with `a[5];` instead of `a[s];` ?

Comment: For decay to pointer you'd need the parameter type to be `T*`, not `T*&`. The latter would only work with actual pointers.

Comment: @interjay I've tested with `T*` and it decayed, so if you make an answer of the comment (explaining why `T*` decays while `T*&` does not) I'll accept the answer.

Comment: [dcl.init.ref]/p5: "The usual lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), **array-to-pointer** (4.2), and function-to-pointer standard conversions are not needed, and therefore are suppressed, when such direct bindings to lvalues are done." Note that the pointer returned from the array-to-pointer conversion will be an rvalue, so it wouldn't work anyway if it occurred since you can't initialize a non-const lvalue-reference with an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During template argument deduction, the array-to-pointer conversion is only used if the function template parameter's type is not a reference.

> **§14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call
>   [temp.deduct.call]**
>
> 1 Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the
>   corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below.
>   [...]
>
> 2 If `P` is not a reference type:
>
> - If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of `A` for
>     type deduction; otherwise,
> - [...]