# Overload resolution and array-to-pointer decay - why is int (&a)[2] and int* a considered equally exact regarding overload resolution

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, overload-resolution

**tl;dr;**
why is - regarding overload resolution / function declaration - the `pointer type` treated <s>as a more</s> equally exact match than the `array type`, even though a passed variable is really of type `array type` and not "just" of `pointer type`

---

I already looked at some of the equivalent questions (e.g. [21972652](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972652/array-decay-to-pointer-and-overload-resolution), [29602638](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602638/runtime-sized-arrays-and-pointer-decay) and [72929287](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929287/what-part-of-overload-resolution-or-more-generally-of-the-function-call-process)) regarding overload resolution and array-to-pointer decay and learned that the compiler will treat `void foo(int (&a)[3]);` and `void foo(int* a);` for the same when passing in `int bar[3];`, but I do not really understand why it does so (despite the fact that it is stated to do so in the specification).

Consider the following example, which does not compile due to ambiguous function call ([online](https://godbolt.org/z/reqnWoWrj)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void foo(int (&a)[2])
{
    std::cout << "Called concrete foo with N = 2";
}

void foo(int* a)
{
    std::cout << "Called pointer foo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a1[] = { 0x00 };
    int a2[] = { 0x00, 0x01 };
    int a3[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };

    foo(a1);
    foo(a2);
    foo(a3);
}
```

My naive understanding tells me, that for the function call `foo(a2)`, `int (&a)[2]` should be more concrete / exact regarding overload resolution than `int* a`, because the actual type of the variable a2 is `int[2]` (array type) and not `int*` (pointer type).

So why does the compiler not favor `void foo(int (&a)[2])` over `void foo(int* a)`?

Kind regards

---

this first part of the question (why does the compiler not favor `void foo(int (&a)[2])` over `void foo(int* a)`) is already answered and marked as accepted, since this was my initial question, nevertheless it would be nice if someone could explain some reasoning behind this decision, i.e. why it is the way it is and whether there is any counter example (besides backward compatibility) to favor `void foo(int (&a)[2])` over `void foo(int* a)`.

Comment: Dupe: [Templates vs Similar Non-Template Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095439/templates-vs-similar-non-template-functions)

Comment: That is not a duplicate at all - I am not asking whether a regular function is preferred over a function template. See especially my second example code. It's about: why is `int (&a)[N]` and `int* a` considered equally exact regarding overload resolution?

Comment: the quote from the standard isnt that much related to why the call is ambiguous. The types of the functions differ, if they would be of same type defining both would result in a compiler error. Its rather a matter of overload resolution

Comment: Another dupe: [Array reference binding vs. array-to-pointer conversion with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71671963/array-reference-binding-vs-array-to-pointer-conversion-with-templates)

Comment: All of this can be avoided by using `std::array`, which does not decay, and `void foo(int&)`. `std::vector` and `std::span` also come to mine. But if you really need to pass a C-style array you should always pass it with a `std::size_t length`.

Comment: @AnoopRana: Thanks for the second reference, but once again it is not a dupe, because the linked issue is once again about templates, but my concrete question is "mentioned" in the author's statement `careful reading of overload resolution rules makes it clear why it fails`. Fortunately, your written answer down below finally addresses my real question. @Goswin von Brederlow: thank's for the comment, I am aware of your notes but my question was not about "how to circumvent array-to-pointer decay" or alternatives to passing an "array type" array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@463035818_is_not_a_number already explained in their answer why `void foo(int* a);` is a better match than `template<std::size_t N> void foo(int (&a)[N])`.

This answer only applies to the second example in the question:

```cpp
void foo(int (&a)[2]);
void foo(int* a);

// why is this call ambiguous?
int arr[2];
foo(arr);
```

---

#### 1. Finding the best matching function

Both functions can be found by name lookup, are [candidate functions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.call.func#3) and [viable functions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.viable).

So which function will be called (or if the call is ambiguous) is based on wether any of them is a **better** viable function than the other.

As per [12.4.3 Best viable function [over.match.best] (2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2):

> <sup>(2)</sup> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments *i*, ICS*i*(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS*i*(F2), and then
> [...]
> <sup>(2.1)</sup> for some argument *j*, **ICS*j*(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICS*j*(F2)**, [...]

So to determine if any of the two functions is better we need to check the conversion sequences of their arguments and compare them.

---

#### 2. Comparing the conversion sequences

###### 2.1 Required conversion sequences

Let's first determine which conversion sequences we need for both calls:

- `void foo(int (&a)[2]);`
  only requires the **identity conversion sequence**, as per [12.4.3.1.4 Reference binding [over.ics.ref] (1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.best.ics#over.ics.ref-1):

  > <sup>(1)</sup> When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion [...]
- `void foo(int* a);`
  requires a conversion sequence consisting of an **Array-to-pointer conversion** conversion, as per [7.3.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array] (1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.array#1):

  > <sup>(1)</sup> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. [...]

###### 2.2 Which conversion sequence is better?

To determine which conversion sequence is better we need to reference [12.4.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank) - in this case mainly paragraph [(3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3) and [(4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#4).

> <sup>(1)</sup> This subclause defines a partial ordering of implicit conversion sequences based on the relationships *better conversion sequence* and *better conversion*. If an implicit conversion sequence S1 is defined by these rules to be a better conversion sequence than S2, then it is also the case that S2 is a *worse conversion sequence* than S1. If conversion sequence S1 is neither better than nor worse than conversion sequence S2, S1 and S2 are said to be *indistinguishable conversion sequences*.

###### 2.3 Is one of the conversion sequences a subsequence of the other?

<sup>Note: we'll skip (3.1) because it only applies to list-initialization.</sup>

So let's start with the first condition, [(3.2.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2.1):

> <sup>(3.2)</sup> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if:
>
> - <sup>(3.2.1)</sup> S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [[over.ics.scs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.scs), excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence) or, if not that, [...]

<sup>Note: Due to questions about this clause in the comments i'll explain this rule in detail.</sup>

tl;dr: Neither conversion sequence is a subsequence of the other.

To fully understand this rule we need to first define a few terms:

- **sequence** (as in standard conversion sequence) refers to a [mathematical sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence); in essence a sequence in maths is a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) with the additional constraints that the order of elements matters and repetition of elements is allowed.
- **proper subsequence** (or strict subsequence)
  Given Sequences `A` and `B`, if `A` is a subsequence of `B`, and `A` is not equal to `B`, then `A` is a proper subsequence of `B`. ([image])
  (see [subset / proper subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions) - it's the same for sequences)
  A few examples to illustrate the principle:

  - `(A, B)` is a proper subsequence of `(A, B, C, D)` (we can remove elements)
  - `(B, C)` is a proper subsequence of `(A, B, C, D)` (removing is allowed at any position)
  - `(A, B, C)` is **not** a proper subsequence of `(A, C, B, D)` (order matters)
  - `(A)` is **not** a proper subsequence of `(A)` (if both sequences are equal, neither is a proper subsequence of the other)
  - `()` is a proper subsequence of `(A, B, C)` (the empty sequence is a proper subsequence of all non-empty sequences)
- **identity** (as in identity conversion / identity conversion sequence) refers to the mathematical [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) (often shortened to just indentity)

  - The terms identity conversion & identity conversion sequence in this case refers to an empty sequence of conversions (`()`) - applying no conversions to a value always results in the original value: `value ∘ () = value`

So with this we can break down the `(3.2.1)` rule:

- > comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [[over.ics.scs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.scs), excluding any Lvalue Transformation

  - [[over.ics.scs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.scs) describes the way we need to order the conversions (if we have more than one) - because remember ordering **does matter** for sequences.
  - If a conversion sequence contains a Lvalue Transformation we need to remove it before checking for proper subsequences.
- > the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence

  - This is a roundabout way of saying that an empty conversion sequence is considered a subsequence of any non-empty conversion sequence (one of the rules for proper subsequences).
- > Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if:
  >
  > - S1 is a proper subsequence of S2

  - So we need to check if S1 is a proper subsequence of S2, and if it is then S1 is better than S2

So now let's apply this to our specific case:

- We have sequence S1 for `foo(int (&a)[2])`: `()` (identity conversion sequence)
- and sequence S2 for `foo(int* a);`: `("Array-to-pointer conversion")`

Now we need to remove Lvalue-conversions.
In [12.4.3.1.1 Standard conversion sequences [over.ics.scs] (3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.best.ics#over.ics.scs-3) Array-to-pointer conversion is listed as an Lvalue-conversion, therefore we must remove it from S2.

So S2 = `()`

Now we need to check if S1 is a proper subsequence of S2.

It can't be a proper subsequence because S1 = S2, therefore this rule does not apply.

##### 2.4 ranking the conversion sequences

Next we need to check the rank of the conversion sequences as per [(3.2.2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2.2)

> <sup>(3.2.2)</sup> the rank of S1 is better than the rank of S2, or S1 and S2 have the same rank and are distinguishable by the rules in the paragraph below, or, if not that,

There are three possible ranks for conversions: Exact Match, Promotion or Conversion, as per [12.4.3.1.1 Standard conversion sequences [over.ics.scs] (3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.best.ics#over.ics.scs-3):

> <sup>(3)</sup> Each conversion [...] also has an associated rank (Exact Match, Promotion, or Conversion). These are used to rank standard conversion sequences. The rank of a conversion sequence is determined by considering the rank of each conversion in the sequence and the rank of any reference binding. If any of those has Conversion rank, the sequence has Conversion rank; otherwise, if any of those has Promotion rank, the sequence has Promotion rank; otherwise, the sequence has Exact Match rank.
>
> | Conversion | Category | Rank |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | No conversions required | Identity | Exact Match |
> | Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion | Lvalue Transformation | Exact Match |
> | Array-to-pointer conversion | Lvalue Transformation | Exact Match |
> | Function-to-pointer conversion | Lvalue Transformation | Exact Match |
> | Qualification conversions | Qualification Adjustment | Exact Match |
> | Function pointer conversion | Qualification Adjustment | Exact Match |
> | Integral promotions | Promotion | Promotion |
> | Floating-point promotion | Promotion | Promotion |
> | Integral conversions | Conversion | Conversion |
> | Floating-point conversions | Conversion | Conversion |
> | Floating-integral conversions | Conversion | Conversion |
> | Pointer conversions | Conversion | Conversion |
> | Pointer-to-member conversions | Conversion | Conversion |
> | Boolean conversions | Conversion | Conversion |

The ordering of which is as follows:

[12.4.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank] (4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#4)

> <sup>(4)</sup> Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact Match is a better conversion than a Promotion, which is a better conversion than a Conversion. Two conversion sequences with the same rank are indistinguishable unless one of the following rules applies: [...]

(there are also a bunch of exceptions listed in that paragraph, but none of them apply to the given example)

So from the above table:

- The identity conversion has a rank of "Exact Match"
- The Array-to-pointer conversion has a rank of "Exact Match"

So both conversion sequences have the "Exact Match" rank, so we need to check if one of the rules below [(3.2.2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2.2) applies to our case:

- > <sup>(3.2.3)</sup> S1 and S2 include reference bindings [...]
  > <sup>(3.2.4)</sup> S1 and S2 include reference bindings [...]

  Only one overload of `foo` binds by reference, therefore both subclauses don't apply.
- > <sup>(3.2.5)</sup> S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion [...]

  Neither S1 nor S2 contain a qualification conversion, therefore this subclause doesn't apply.
- > <sup>(3.2.6)</sup> S1 and S2 include reference bindings [...]

  Doesn't apply - see reasoning for (3.2.3) / (3.2.4)

So there are unfortunately no subclauses that would make the two conversion sequences distinguishable.

##### 2.5 The conversion sequences are indistinguishable

The only paragraph left from [[over.ics.rank]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank) is (3.3) - which deals with user-defined conversion sequences.

So we've run out of paragraphs that could resolve the ambiguity - therefore the conversion sequences required for the two functions are **indistinguishable conversion sequences**.

---

#### 3. Resolution

Due to the conversion sequences of both `foo`s being indistinguishable, neither function is a better viable function.

So the second part of [12.4.3 Best viable function[over.match.best] (3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#3) applies:

> If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than all other viable functions, then it is the one selected by overload resolution; **otherwise the call is ill-formed**.

So the call is ill-formed and will result in an ambiguous function call error.

---

#### 4. A look into the future

There is an open core language issue for exactly this case from 2013: [CWG 1789](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1789)

> The current rules make an example like
>
> ```cpp
> template<class T, size_t N> void foo(T (&)[N]);
> template<class T> void foo(T *t);
>
> int arr[3]{1, 2, 3};
> foo(arr);
> ```
>
> ambiguous, even though the first is an identity match and the second requires an lvalue transformation. Is this desirable?

with a proposed solution from 2021, that suggests adding another bullet to [12.4.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank] (3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3) in the form of:

> S1 is a reference binding to an array and S2 is an array-to-pointer conversion (7.3.3 [conv.array]).
> *[Example 7:*
>
> ```cpp
>  template<class T, unsigned N> void f(T (&)[N]); // #1
>  template<class T> void f(T *t);                 // #2
>  int r[3]{1, 2, 3};
>  void g() {
>    f(r);    // OK: calls #1
>  }
> ```
>
> *—end example]*

This would make the conversion sequence for `void foo(int (&a)[2]);` better than the one of `void foo(int* a);` and therefore resolve the ambiguity. (`void foo(int (&a)[2]);` would always be called)

Unfortunately it is still in the [Review state](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#Issue%20Status), so it is unclear when (or even if) it will be included in the standard.

##### 4.1 How to bypass the issue in C++20

There is a simple way to avoid the ambiguity: Make `void foo(int*)` a template ([non-templated functions are preferred over templated ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33095469/8411406)).

So this set of functions would not be ambiguous:

```cpp
void foo(int (&)[2]) {}

template<class = void>
void foo(int*) {}
```

Another option would be to always use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) - that also avoids most of the common pitfalls of c-style arrays. ([What's wrong with arrays?](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#arrays))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It perfectly reflects the "chain" of specifications resulting in the observed behaviour. Nevertheless, now I am still curious "why" it is like it is and if there are any examples showcasing why it has to be like it is (i.e. whether there is some counter-example, besides "backwards compatibility)

Comment: @Chilippso I've updated my answer - unfortunately there's nothing to be found in terms of standard proposals regarding references to arrays in the context of overload resolution. So unfortunately there's not an obvious reason why it is the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for your extra efforts. Regarding backwards-compatibility I was thinking about legacy code and not regarding C. But never mind, it is like it is anyway. By the way, as stated in a comment for another answer, `over.ics.rank#3.1.2` tells that S1 is better than S2 if S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 *comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], **excluding `any` Lvalue Transformation`;` the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of `any` non-identity conversion sequence*** - because of the `;` I am pensive

Comment: @Chilippso i've elaborated the whole conversion sequence ranking in my latest edit and also added comments to all other paragraphs in [over.ics.rank] (3.1.2) elaborating why they don't apply. Sorry in advance for wikipedia links and the giant wall of text :D

Comment: @Chilippso i managed to find a core issue that is direcly related to this ambiguity ([CWG 1789](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1789)) - it looks like the standard comittee is aware of the ambiguity and are planning to fix it. Unfortunately it's only in the review stage. I've also edited my answer to include a reference to said core issue.

Comment: thank you once again for your investigations. That reference perfectly addresses my "issue" and follows my own expectation that an identity-conversion has to be considered as the best match.

Answer (score 1):

> So why does the compiler not favor void `foo(int (&a)[2])` over void `foo(int* a)`?

Because the *array to pointer conversion* is **not considered** worse than the *identity conversion*. This can be seen from [ics.rank-3.2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over#ics.rank-3.2.1) which states:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> - **S1 is a proper subsequence of S2** (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], **excluding any Lvalue Transformation**; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence) or, if not that,

(emphasis mine)

The important thing to note here is that array to pointer conversion is *lvalue transformation*.

Comment: Maybe I was just unable to ask properly, but thank you for finally addressing my question. This is an interesting "spot" regarding my question. Despite your emphasised excerpt, it also states `the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of **any** non-identity conversion sequence`. The semicolon makes me think, whether the previous statement `excluding any Lvalue Transformation` also applies to the statement quoted before. Nevertheless, even though the answer tends into the right direction, it's not as complete than the other one, so it's (currently) not the accepted one